# JavaScript if-elseif-statement

Tags: javascript

In PHP, the different if-elseif-scenarios rule each other out, right? I am a little confused, I don't seem to figure out why this is not the case in JavaScript here. Can anybody tell me how to simplify this?

(This statement is connected to radio-buttons and is supposed to style the selected radio button differently. However, when I do not include all the `remove`-parts, clicking one and then another one leaves me with both of them styled as "selected")

```
$("#item-upload-form input").on("change", function() {


var hello = $("input[name='category_select']:checked", "#item-upload-form").val();


if(hello == 1){
   $("#handy").addClass("selected");
   $("#pc").removeClass("selected");
   $("#notebook").removeClass("selected");

 } else if (hello == 2){
   $("#pc").addClass("selected");
   $("#handy").removeClass("selected");
   $("#notebook").removeClass("selected");

 } else if (hello == 3){
   $("#notebook").addClass("selected");
   $("#pc").removeClass("selected");
   $("#handy").removeClass("selected");
 }

});
```

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please, including the relevant HTML?

Comment: It's actually pretty simple - while you think of PHP as re-rendering the page freshly based on the PHP document each time, JavaScript simply alters the current state in the given way. If you add a class, and don't specifically tell it to remove a certain class, it won't remove it; and it'll stay that way until the page completely reloads. One way you could reduce this code is with toggleClass: `$('etc').toggleClass("selected", giveABooleanVarHere)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Katana314 had the right answer to the question you're asking. Javascript isn't refreshing the page on each call so the class will stay on the element until you remove it. Might be a little cleaner this way...

```
$("#item-upload-form input").on("change", function() {


var hello = $("input[name='category_select']:checked", "#item-upload-form").val();

// find any element that has the selected class and remove it
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');

// then add it to which ever element needs it.
if(hello == 1){
   $("#handy").addClass("selected");
 } else if (hello == 2){
   $("#pc").addClass("selected");
 } else if (hello == 3){
   $("#notebook").addClass("selected");
 }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using two selectors and checking hello with the value will only work for those whose both value returns the same value. If both selector value results in different values then your condition never match.

So, it will only match if both values are the same.

Comment: okay, thanks! :-) Any idea how I can write this function without using hundreds of lines?

Comment: what you want? both values must be same or any value match?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What I need to achieve is to have only one radio-button with the class `selected` at a time. So, when a user clicks on `1` all except for `1` should not have the class `selected`.

Comment: then, why are you using two selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep only calls to addClass(). The code would look like this:

```
if(hello == 1){
   $("#handy").addClass("selected");
 } else if (hello == 2){
   $("#pc").addClass("selected");
 } else if (hello == 3){
   $("#notebook").addClass("selected");
 }
```

What happens when you click on radio buttons?
R: Each time it will run only ONE branch. Successive clicks will only addClass to current element, and maintain classes of previous elements.

Comment: and exactly that was my problem! :-) @Katana314's comment made me figure it out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Why not let jQuery do all of the work for you - this way you can add/remove selections without updating your code:

```
$("#item-upload-form input").on("change", function (ele) {
    $("#item-upload-form input").each(function(  ) {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(this).addClass("selected")
        } else{
            $(this).removeClass("selected") ;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, yes, if-else-blocks will stop evaluating if a match is found.

Suggestion 1:
Try using `===` instead of `==`.
`===` checks both if the value and type are the same.

`== 1` will pass as true for many things, including `'1' == 1` and `true == 1`. I don't know what hello actually is, but you might be getting a false positive.

Suggestion 2:
Here is a revised code suggestion (instead of if-else blocks)

```
$("#handy").toggleClass("selected", (hello === 1));
$("#pc").toggleClass("selected", (hello === 2));
$("#notebook").toggleClass("selected", (hello === 3));
```